# Assume $f(x)=(1+x)^n\in \mathbb F_p[x]$, can we find a general formula for $f(x)$?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

We know that $(1+x)^n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}x^n \in \mathbb Q[x]$. Assume $f(x)=(1+x)^n\in \mathbb F_p[x]$, when $n>p,$ can we find a general formula for $f(x)$?

Comment: Presumably you are looking for [Lucas's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas's_theorem). That's what you get when you combine the binomial formula with freshman's dream: $(1+x)^{p^\ell}=1+x^{p^\ell}$ in the ring $\Bbb{F}_p[x]$.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: I didn't know this identity had a name. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: $(1+x)^n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}x^n$ stays true in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$. All you have to do is using that $p = 0$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$ and simplify the *integer* $\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}$ accordingly

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen, Thanks for response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1+x)^{p^\ell}=\sum_{k=0}^{p^\ell}\binom{p^\ell}{k}x^k$, but for all $1\le k\le p^\ell-1$ we have $\binom{p^\ell}{k}\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ so
$$
(1+x)^{p^\ell}=\sum_{k=0}^{p^\ell}\binom{p^\ell}{k}x^k=1+x^{p^\ell}
$$
in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$.

Then for any $n=p^\ell\cdot m$ where $m<p$ we have
$$
(1+x)^n=(1+x)^{p^\ell\cdot m}=\left((1+x)^{p^\ell}\right)^m=\left(1+x^{p^\ell}\right)^m=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}x^{kp^\ell}.
$$